# Java JButton it is not running truly

Tags: java, jbutton

I added a jbutton with eclipse but it is not seeing correctly. How do I fix it?

[this is screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njWGP.png):
[image]

```
public class GUITest // test class
{
    // block the warnings
    public static void main(String[] args) //main
    {
        System.out.println("start of main");
        /* stackoverflow want to add more details */
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        JButton button = new JButton("Click here");
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new Action());
        System.out.println("end of main");
```

/* stackoverflow want to add more details */
        }

```
    public static class Action implements ActionListener //actionlistener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        { /* stackoverflow want to add more details */
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Clicked");
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setSize(200,200);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("You clicked me!");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame2.add(panel);
            panel.add(label); // some more details

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: always call `setVisible` last.after adding all component .but this seems VGA issue.close eclipse and try to run `graphical processor nvidea` http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/4817i32CB2A6D7D20EC06/image-size/original?v=mpbl-1&px=-1

Comment: Can you post your code as text here...

Comment: Post the code in your main method to the event dispatch thread using `EventQueue.invokeLater`. Seems like there was an issue while painting, most likely due to mis-use of the API. Also, you shouldn't be creating a new frame every time you click the button. Pass the frame instance to `Action` when you creafe it, and store it in a field variable so you can access it withi  `actionPerformed`

Comment: @ AshwinP Thank you so much. I run eclipse with High-Performance NVIDIA and it run correctly.

Comment: @FastSnail Sorry, I wanted to thank you. Your post is useful for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and It will working fine. Can you please check your Graphics Driver or other things.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Ashwin Parmar
 */
public class GUITest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        JButton button = new JButton("Click here");
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new Action());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("End");
    }

    public static class Action implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Clicked");
            frame2.setSize(200,200);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("You have clicked me!");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame2.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I ran eclipse with High performance graphic card and run correct. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

- Always create and modify the UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread
- Wherever possible, call `setVisible` last, after you have established the basic UI. You will be required to call `revalidate` and `repaint` if you add components after the window is made visible.

For example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame.add(panel);
            JButton button = new JButton("Click here");
            panel.add(button);
            button.addActionListener(new Action());             
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Do the same thing within your `ActionListener`.

See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: Thank for interesting but my problem was graphic card. In addition I can not running your code. ClassNotFoundException is not undefined. What import must I add?

Comment: @HalilReis add following imports
`import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I ran program normally default graphic card and your code ran perfectly. Thank you too.